# How can I access the volume I created in docker compose via dockerfile?

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a volume in docker compose and want to copy files into it. I need docker file for this. However, I don't know how to access the volume I created in docker compose via dockerfile. How can I do it?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
 
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5433:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: test@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: test
    depends_on: 
      - postgres

  web:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: spring/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./test-volume:/opt/_LIB/
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ...

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/jetty/webapps/*
COPY spring/target/*.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
#CMD ["java", "-jar", "$JETTY_HOME/start.jar"]
```

Comment: You can't. Dockerfiles deal with image creation and the volume is attached to a container instance. One image can be the origin of multiple container instances.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I created a volume with Dcoker compose. I want to copy file into volume. But this shouldn't happen manually. So I want to do it on dockerfile. Or by any means possible.

Comment: The build of the Dockerfile happens before anything you make with docker-compose, so this is not possible. Try to describe what's your goal (copying the file is how you're trying to achieve some objective, not the objective) so I may try to help.

Answer (score 0):

> [How can I] access the volume I created in docker compose via dockerfile?

You can't.  It doesn't exist yet.  Everything in the Compose `build:` block happens before any other option in the Compose file is considered; you don't get to see `volumes:`, or `environment:` variables, or access other containers on `networks:` (even the automatically-provided `default` network).

The way the `postgres` image handles this is through an *entrypoint wrapper script* that creates the database if it doesn't exist.  You can write a similar script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# If the data files don't exist yet, copy them in
if [ ! -f /opt/_LIB/data.txt ]; then
  java -cp "$JETTY_HOME/start.jar" com.example.tools.SeedData /opt/_LIB
fi

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Replace the `java` command with whatever invocation would copy the data files from somewhere else in the image into the volume; even just a `cp -r` is fine, so long as the source data is somewhere other than the data directory.  You can similarly change the logic to overwrite the old content if it exists, or if you have some way to merge the old and new files, you can do that too.

In your Dockerfile you can then leave your `CMD` as-is, but make sure to `COPY` this script into your image and make it the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```bash
FROM ...

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/jetty/webapps/*
COPY spring/target/*.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin                         # <-- ADD

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]               # <-- ADD
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/var/lib/jetty/webapps/start.jar"]  # unmodified
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` line *must* use JSON-array syntax (which in turn means it can't include environment-variable references; I've corrected this in the `CMD`).  The script needs to be executable (run `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` on the host system if needed).

(There is one corner case around Docker named volumes that some questions will try to take advantage of, but I don't generally recommend it.  In your example the `/opt/_LIB` container directory uses a bind-mounted host directory so this trick won't work; it also doesn't work if you ever want to change the content in the image, or if you're deploying to an environment that's not native Docker.)